# Not able to authenticate to authdeamon socket

Tags: sockets, smtp, centos, exim

### I am getting an error while trying to add my SMTP server in my Gmail account. Adding POP3 went fine but google returns this error when trying to add SMTP:

```
435 Unable to authenticate at present code(435)
```

My mailserver gives this respons in the logfile:

```
# tail -f /var/log/exim/main.log

2014-08-13 14:00:41 plain authenticator failed for (mail-ig0-f171.google.com) [209.85.213.171]: 435 Unable to authenticate at present (set_id=123testmail@domain.com): failed to connect to socket /var/spool/authdaemon/socket: Permission denied
```

By default the permissions for the socket is as follows:

```
# ls -al /var/spool/authdaemon/socket
srwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Aug 13 00:38 /var/spool/authdaemon/socket
```

Also while recieving email i get this error in Exim's logfile:

```
2014-08-13 14:38:19 1XHZGR-0005Il-LD == 123testmail@domain.com R=vdomain T=vmail defer (13): Permission denied: failed to open tmp/1407940699.H500223P20471.mail.domain.com (10 tries)
```

Server is running on CentOS 6 with Courier-imap

Comment: Post the complete authenticator definitions in your post.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what you mean.